# How do I combine two functions to one?

Tags: jquery

How do I combine two functions to one ?

Basicially I like to run a function if the last element of 
`variant--group` **"change"**` or is **"checked"**

**"change" function:**

```
$(".variant--group").last().find(".option--input").on("change", function() {
//alert
});
```

**"checked" function:**

```
$(".variant--group").last().find(".option--input").attr("checked", function() {
//alert
});
```

Comment: ___"checked"___ , surely second one throw error

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change','.option',function(){
        alert('Changed');
    });


});
</script>

<body>

    <select class="option">
        <option>apple</option>
        <option>mango</option>
        <option>orange</option>
    </select>

Car<input type="checkbox" class="option" value="Car" />
Bike<input type="checkbox" class="option" value="Bike" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need two functions to check for a change for different input types. The .on("change") event will fire for a checkbox or textbox when the value is changed. After the event fires and a change is found, you may want to check if the checkbox is checked or not, to do so see below:

```
$(".variant--group").last().find(".option--input").is(":checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a single event handler function for 2 events 
You can combine 2 event handlers together using the following syntax

```
$("<Selector>").on("change blur",function(){
// alert
});
```

working fiddle
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKqJaw